# PowerEdge T110 ii and PERC H200 battery?

Tags: windows, dell-poweredge, cache, dell-perc

I'm confused.

I have a **PowerEdge T110 ii** server with a **PERC S100 card**, sad to say, the S100 does not have drivers for Windows 2012 R2, Dell recommends you upgrade your PERC card or forget about the RAID on the server.

Looking up the compatible PERC cards for the server, the **PERC H200** seems to fit nicely, but apparently it doesn't have a **battery for write caching** or so most of the sites I looked up say, not having a battery for the card causes the disks performance to go very bad.

By chance, I found "[Cable for PERC H200 Controller for T110 II Chassis - Kit](http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=uk&l=en&s=dhs&cs=ukdhs1&sku=470-12373)" and the overview reads the following:

[image]

Now I'm very confused, does the H200 support a battery for caching or not?

Thanks,

Comment: You're best off calling Dell directly for this. Your sales rep would be more than happy to sell you something if it's at all possible, I'm sure :)

Comment: Seriously, why do people not contact the vendor for these types of questions? One of the things that frustrates me to no end is when people waste countless hours trolling the internet for an answer when a phone call to the vendor could answer it in minutes.

Comment: Note that S100 and S110 are software-based RAID solutions with minimal logics to allow for reading an array's state and basic I/O to boot off the operating system. They neither have an own cache nor a battery to back it up. Also keep in mind that although Dell does not support other RAID controllers than the H200 in the T110,  any generic PCIe controller (Adaptec, LSI/3Ware or rebrands) very likely will work. As the T110 does not even has a hot-swap backplane, you would not have to waste time researching compatibility for it too.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, the information in the page is wrong.

Contacted Dell directly, and here is their answer:

> No, the H200 does not have cache or use a battery.
>
> The description on that sales page is wrong. If you look at the
>   technical specs that is a SAS cable. It is the cable that connects
>   from the H200 to the backplane. The description is for a battery
>   cable, but the part is actually an H200 SAS cable for a backplane.
>
> The H200 is the top controller for a T110 II. There is not a supported
>   controller option that has cache memory. The H700/H710/PERC 6
>   controllers that have cache are quite expensive. The T110 is an entry
>   level server and we designed it to function with lower end RAID
>   controllers that are more cost effective. The higher end PERCs are
>   validated for the T310 and higher for 11th generation tower servers.
>
> Thanks